# using React-native init, a new iOS app can't build in Xcode, build error 'ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-cli

steps to reproduce:

`react-native init FirstProject`
`cd FirstProject`
`open ios/FirstProject.xcodeproj`

... Xcode opens the project:

[image]

I select build target iOS Simulator -> Iphone XR

A terminal window opens in the background:

[image]

However, Xcode returns a build error:

```
ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

shown with warnings here https://gist.github.com/jasonfb/7b51a260df419590c6fadda93fb49348

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be opening the workspace, not the project file as indicated per instructions at the end of the project creation script:

````
    • cd "/Users/xxx/FirstProject" && npx react-native run-ios
    - or -
    • Open FirstProject/ios/FirstProject.xcworkspace in Xcode or run "xed -b ios"
    • Hit the Run button```
````